# Using Codeception, Symfony2 Functional Testing a service how do I add assertions?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, codeception

Summary: I want to use Module assertions in my Tests.

Previously I have tested Symfony2 services using PHPUnit tests. This is ok but I would like to use some of the facilities that the Codeception Symfony2 Module provides as well as the cleaner testing style.

I created a new suite with the following services.suite.yml

```
class_name: ServiceGuy
  modules:
    enabled: [Symfony2, Doctrine2, Filesystem, ServiceHelper]
```

I ran build and generate:cest and have a ServiceCest.php test file with

```
public function getServiceUrl(\ServiceGuy $I) {
    $this->myservice = $I->grabServiceFromContainer("myservice");
    $I->wantTo("get service URL");
    $I->seeTrue("http://example.com/services" 
                  ==  $this->ecservice->getServiceUrl());
}
```

This test passes because I added an assertion function to my ServiceHelper.php file.

```
class ServiceHelper extends \Codeception\Module    {
  function seeTrue($flag) {
    $this->assertTrue($flag);
  }
}
```

The Module class has a rich set of assertion functions that I would like to be able to use directly in my tests. But I don't think module object is available to the test.  It would seem repetitive to have to add a range of assertion functions to the ServiceHelper. 
Is there a better way?

For example in the phpunit test I might have these assertions.

$station = $ecservice->getStation("Auckland");

$this->assertEquals(1,count($stations));
   $this->assertEquals('Auckland',$station->getDisplayName());

My question is whether there is a way to have all these assertions in the functional test, or whether I have to move a lot of test specific assertions into the helper.

The ***Unit*** module appears to provide many of these facilities - but is deprecated.

I tried putting \PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertEquals(1,count($stations));
in the test - but this throws an exception on failure that is not handled by the test harness.

Thanks Andrew

PS I'd tag this 'codeception' but I don't have the points yet. perhaps someone else can.

Answer (score 2):

Yep. We deprecated it because of too much misuses.

In your case you should either use classical PHPUnit's testing style.
Codeception have 2 options, generate:test - to get some of Codeception helpers or generate:phpunit to get plain PHPUnit test with no magic.

Please read my post on this. There I have some tips, like working with container in unit tests.

http://codeception.com/02-12-2013/testing-symfony2.html